# Vectorizing finding the row-wise mean of data frames within lists within lists

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a list of sublists. Each sublist contains an identical data frame (identical except for the data inside it) and a 'yes/no' label. I'd like to find the row-wise mean of the data frames, if the yes/no label is TRUE.

```
#Create the data frames
id <- c("a", "b", "c")
df1 <- data.frame(id=id, data=c(1, 2, 3))
df2 <- df1
df3 <- data.frame(id=id, data=c(1000, 2000, 3000))

#Create the sublists that will store the data frame and the yes/no variable
sub1 <- list(data=df1, useMe=TRUE)
sub2 <- list(data=df2, useMe=TRUE)
sub3 <- list(data=df3, useMe=FALSE)

#Store the sublists in a main list
main <- list(sub1, sub2, sub3)
```

I want a vectorized function that will return the row-wise average of the data frames, but only if `$useMe==TRUE`, like so:

```
> desiredFun(main)
   id  data
1   a     1
2   b     2
3   c     3
```

Comment: When you say "identical", do you mean `id` is always the same for each row in the data.frame and only the `data` column values differ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Really each sublist should probably be an object, but I haven't dug into OOP in R yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly general way to approach this problem:

```
# Extract the "data" portion of each "main" list element
# (using lapply to return a list)
AllData <- lapply(main, "[[", "data")
# Extract the "useMe" portion of each "main" list element
# using sapply to return a vector)
UseMe <- sapply(main, "[[", "useMe")
# Select the "data" list elements where the "useMe" vector elements are TRUE
# and rbind all the data.frames together
Data <- do.call(rbind, AllData[UseMe])
library(plyr)
# Aggregate the resulting data.frame
Avg <- ddply(Data, "id", summarize, data=mean(data))
```

Comment: Can you explain why the lapply(x, "[["... syntax works? I would not have guessed that it would, since "[[" is not a function as far as I know.

Comment: Oh but it is. You can use it like any other. Take the instance of `x<-list(a=1:3, b=letters, c=LETTERS)`. You can use `x[["b"]]` to get the lowercase letters element, or equivalently: `"[["(x, "b")`. Everything in R is a function.